# How do I delete a registry key?

Tags: vb.net, regedit, registrykey

This is my code:

```
Dim exePath As String = Application.ExecutablePath()
Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store", True)
key.DeleteValue(exePath)
```

But I don't know why the application doesn't delete that key.

Example: It finds the key but it doesn't delete that key

[image]

Comment: Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: @Crowcoder no, only if i manually delete the key.

Comment: When you open the application,it create that key.......I just want delete "..\Store\That Key" (That key=File path.....). there is no exception launched but it does not delete that key

Comment: Because you are not deleting the key... Try `My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store")`

Comment: So ***you want to delete a value from a key***? Then please adjust your question. Also are you compiling 32 or 64?

Comment: Yes sorry, the code?

Comment: Yes the code...

Comment: no, what is the correct code.....(lol)?

Comment: Have you tried running as admin, you can try that. Also if compiling for 32 bit try 64 and or AnyCpu.

Comment: Im already opening the application as an administrator but it does not delete the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value is created automatically by the system when starting the application, meaning you cannot remove it ***while your app is running***.

You can delete it after your app has closed if you want, but you must delete it from a separate application *and* it will be re-created again the next time you launch your app.

Starting a simple `cmd` instance to do the deleting for you is enough:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL & reg delete ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store"" /v """ & Application.ExecutablePath & """ /f")
psi.CreateNoWindow = True
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(psi)
```

Comment: It doesn't give me any error but the app still doesn't delete that value

Comment: @HeyMyBoy : What's the **exact** value of `Application.ExecutablePath`?

Comment: In this case "C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\Games.exe"

Comment: @HeyMyBoy : And that is the exact value? For instance if you put `MessageBox.Show(Application.ExecutablePath)` in your code it will show what you just wrote?

Comment: If the file is in that path yes

Comment: @HeyMyBoy : Hmm, it's a very odd problem you're experiencing... If you inside my code replace `RegKey.DeleteValue(...)` with `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\RegValues.txt", String.Join(Environment.NewLine, RegKey.GetValueNames()))` it should create a file on your desktop called `RegValues.txt` - is the value you want to remove present in that file?

Comment: Yes, i want remove the value in that list

Comment: @HeyMyBoy : So you find it in the `RegValues.txt` file? When the value initially is created, is it created automatically by the system or do you create it yourself inside your application?

Comment: When you open the application automatically the system(pc) create that value in the registry

Comment: @HeyMyBoy : Ah, well then that's your problem. You cannot delete it while your app is running. If you want to delete it when _closing_ your app you'll have to run a separate application to do it for you (a simple cmd instance works fine for this).

Comment: @HeyMyBoy : Glad I could help, though I wouldn't be too quick with accepting this as the answer. First you need to ensure that it works the way you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

In order to delete the key,use the **`DeleteSubKey`** method. An example would look like this:

```
My.computer.Registry.Currentuser.DeleteSubKey(keypath)
```

However, [according to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-delete-a-registry-key), exceptions may occur if

1. The name of the key is nothing or null
2. The user doesn't have required permission to delete/read/write the key
3. The key name exceeds 255 characters
4. The key is set to read-only

Comment: What should i do .-.?

Comment: But the code doesn't delete that specific value right?

Comment: If the value is always different how do I delete the value?,The value name is the same as the application path

Comment: You have seen the photo, can you write the entire / correct code please?

Comment: ow...u dont want to delete the key but the value...r8??

Comment: Bro i want delete C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\Games.exe

Comment: which is equivalent to the directory of when you open the file,I want to eliminate that but it is not always the same.

Comment: i'm not getting it...r u tryin to delete a file or reg key value?

Comment: I'm trying to delete a registry key value (In this case "C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\Games.exe")

Comment: well in that case,ur code should work fine...try using the fike path instead off using a variable(it makes no sense bt still try)

Comment: and please also try **APPLICATION.STARTUPPATH**

Comment: Yes but I don't know why it tells me that there is no such file,Then as I told you it is based on the file directory (it changes continuously)

Comment: You mean `My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store", True).DeleteValue("C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\Games.exe")` right?? because it not works

Comment: Ok no, it works but the value it's not always the same, should i use a variable right?

Comment: If i use this code the app doesn't delete the value But the application doesn't give me any errors`Dim ThisAppPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
        My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store", True).DeleteValue(ThisAppPath)`

Comment: u said the vaue isn't always the same?? then try **APPLICATION.STARTIPPATH** and see if it works

Comment: It doesn't work because.....`application.StartUpPath`....example(C:\Users\Public\Desktop) while `Application.ExecutablePath` (C:\Users\Public\Desktop\File.exe)